# How can I solve this precedence graph?

Tags: graph, operator-precedence

This is my class assignment and I don't know how I can construct a precedence graph for :

- S1: x=0
- S2: x=x+1
- S3: y=2
- S4: z=y
- S5: x=x+2
- S6: y=x+z
- S7: z=4

I thought it would be like:

- S1 goes to S2, S5, and S6
- S2 goes to S5 and S6
- S3 goes to S4 and S6
- S4 goes to S6
- S5 goes to S6
- S7 goes to S6

but S7 doesn't go to S6 in the answer.
It looks S7 goes to S6 because the right hand side of S6 has "z".

Please help me out this problem.

[The example of precedence graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7Nx1.png)

Comment: What do you mean by a precedence graph? Do you have an example?

Comment: Is that possible to put an image on this website? I can show you the example if it's possible...

Comment: Yes! Please edit your post, and click the picture icon

Comment: This image is actually the answer for this problem.

Comment: based on what I have looked up the answer you have in your book might be wrong. I would suggest you talk to your prof. I have often gotten stuck on a problem just to find out the answer key is wrong.  If you find out the answer to it please post it, I'm interested.

Answer (score 0):

`s7` can not goooo to `s6` because once a program is executed it can be reversed.

Moreover `s1` can go to `s3` `s4` or any number below it but `s2` can not refer back to `s1`.

I hope you understand that :)